# iTextSharp DataMatrix barcode capacity

Tags: c#, character-encoding, itext, barcode

I have a specification to implement a DataMatrix barcodes using the 16x36 size. I'm using C# with the iTextSharp library which has a BarcodeDatamatrix class.

Given these barcode dimensions, the specified capacities are:

- Numeric: 64
- Alphanumeric: 46
- Byte: 30

This is taken from the site:

> http://www.barcodephp.com/en/2d/datamatrix/technical

The requirement is to store a 46 character string in the 16x36 symbol.

I'm having a hard time understanding how I can encode a 46 byte string in such a way that it fits into 30 bytes.

Comment: At your liked side, see the table in 'Details' section. Here you see how many bytes required for each kind of data. 30 Bytes=30*8 Bits, ...

Comment: Sure, but how can it store 46 "Alphanumeric" characters? Presumably this requires each character to be encoded in less than 8 bits? If I have a 46 character long string in C# of just 'A', the barcode generation components complain that the data is too long.

Comment: Using `DM_AUTO` I can get a 45 character string into the barcode but that's the limit. I don't know if there's a calculation error or if there's some padding that I don't know about or I'm just not reading the spec correctly.

Comment: I also managed 45 characters of all 'A', but not 46. Then it does allow 46 characters of all '0'. Seems like the 46 characters is a theoretical maximum dependent on the content of the input data supplied. Site [link](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/2d/data-matrix/#Encoding_) quotes: "The encoding mode may be changed to reduce the symbol size in some situations. The chart below illustrates the smallest symbol size, in the best-case scenario, for the amount of data encoded." So doesn't really seem like you can use the Alphanumeric value reliably.